# STL algorithms on containers of boost::function objects

Tags: c++, stl, boost-bind, boost-function

I have the following code that uses a for loop and I would like to use transform, or at least for_each instead, but I can't see how.

```
typedef std::list<boost::function<void(void) > CallbackList;
CallbackList callbacks_;

//...
for(OptionsMap::const_iterator itr = options.begin(); itr != options.end(); ++itr)
{
   callbacks_.push_back(boost::bind(&ClassOutput::write_option_,this,*itr));
}
```

Later on in the code, I actually want to call this collection of nullary function objects.  I'm using a for loop here as well, and it seems like I should be able to use for_each somehow.

```
for(CallbackList::iterator itr = callbacks_.begin(); itr != callbacks_.end(); ++itr)
{    
  (*itr)();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do all this in a single transform call, you I think you need to call bind on itself, because you need a functor which calls boost:bind. That's something I've never attempted. Would you settle for something like this (untested)?

```
struct GetFunc {
    ClassOutput *obj;
    boost::function<void(void) > operator()(const OptionsMap::value_type &v) {
        return boost::bind(&ClassOutput::write_option_, obj, v);
    }
    GetFunc(ClassOutput *obj) : obj(obj) {}
};

transform(options.begin(), options.end(), back_inserter(callbacks_), GetFunc(this));
```

In C++0x you can use a lambda instead of the functor class:

```
transform(options.begin(), options.end(), back_inserter(callbacks_), 
    [this](const OptionsMap::value_type &v) {
        return boost::bind(&ClassOutput::write_option_, this, v);
    }
);
```

Comment: That works with one change.  The argument of operator() should be OptionsMap::value_type.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure out part 2:

```
typedef boost::function<void(void)> NullaryFunc;
for_each(callbacks_.begin(),callbacks_.end(),boost::bind(&NullaryFunc::operator(),_1));
```